# Get File properties of files stored in folders in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have a very simple code to get the list of all files that are stored in my CacheFolder in iPhone

```
 NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Fetch path for document directory
    NSString *documentsPath = (NSMutableString *)[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:APP_NAME];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:&error];
```

However, instead of name only, i want to get each file size and the creation date. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSError *attributesError;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:documentsPath error:&attributesError];

NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
NSDate *creationDate = (NSDate *)[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
```

You can also get the following attributes:

```
NSString * const  NSFileType;
NSString * const  NSFileSize;
NSString * const  NSFileModificationDate;
NSString * const  NSFileReferenceCount;
NSString * const  NSFileDeviceIdentifier;
NSString * const  NSFileOwnerAccountName;
NSString * const  NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName;
NSString * const  NSFilePosixPermissions ;
NSString * const  NSFileSystemNumber;
NSString * const  NSFileSystemFileNumber;
NSString * const  NSFileExtensionHidden;
NSString * const  NSFileHFSCreatorCode;
NSString * const  NSFileHFSTypeCode;
NSString * const  NSFileImmutable;
NSString * const  NSFileAppendOnly;
NSString * const  NSFileCreationDate;
NSString * const  NSFileOwnerAccountID;
NSString * const  NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID;
NSString * const  NSFileBusy;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [NSFileManager's `attributesOfItemAtPath:error` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:), which will return a dictionary with attributes like [`NSFileSize` and `NSFileCreationDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys).